# Why all commercial SPR instruments use angular interrogation?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, surface-chemistry, optical-properties

Surface plasmonic resonance biosensor devices are used to measure analyte concentration, kinetics, affinity, and specificity without any need for labels. This technique involves the bonding of the analyte to a functionalized metal surface (typically gold) in contact with a dielectric medium (glass). The interaction of a light beam with the gold surface changes based on the presence or absence of the analyte which affects the plasmon resonance properties. These changes are then measured to provide quantitative data.

Almost all commercial SPR instruments use angular interrogation, mesuring the angle at which the light beam excites the plasmons. However, additional three SPR detection methods are possible: intensity interrogation, wavelength interrogation, and phase interrogation [PMID: 34615234].

Each method has its pros and cons, for example, phase interrogation has better SPR detection sensitivity but the refractive index change may easily exceed the detection range.

**I would like to understand why angular interrogation strongly dominates the market.** Is it historical? or are there specific properties that make devices that use angular interrogation commercially superior?

Comment: Off the top of my head, based on some surface plasmon work now 40 years ago, using a single laser wavelength and varying the angle is by far the easiest to do experimentally, most reproduceable, and likely the easiest to analyze.